# Auto suggestion list Element's are displayed twice in the result set in Console,what ll be the code to click on list element on the basis of text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

[image]Following is the code to get the list elements name and click on the desired     list element: below is the attachment of result : Console displaying list items twice : what could be the other ways to pick the complex Auto suggestion list 
elements of a web application.

```
package Pages;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Optional;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class Login {

WebDriver driver;
String baseUrl="http://www.flipkart.com/";

@BeforeTest
public void flipkartSetup()
{
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

@Test(priority=0)
public void flipkartLoginpage()
{
    //open the webpage :s
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    //click on Login
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='container']//header/div[2]/div/div[1]/u l/li[8]/a")).click();
    //wait for 30 second
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //Enter mobile into the  text box 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='login-input-wrap']/input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("9999999999");
    //Enter password into the text box 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='tmargin10 login-input-wrap']/input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("abcdefgh");
    //wait for 30seconds
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //click on Login button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='tmargin20 login-btn-wrap']/input[@type='button']")).click();
    //wait for 30seconds
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);



}


@Test(priority=1)

public void FlipkartSearch()
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='container']//form//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("Mobile");
    FlipkartSerchfnctn("mobile");
}


@Parameters("mobile")
@Test(priority=2)

public void FlipkartSerchfnctn(@Optional("mobile") String textToSelect)
{

    List <WebElement> listItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//form[@class='_1WMLwI']//ul/li"));
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    for (int i = 0; i < listItems.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println(listItems.get(i).getText());

        if(listItems.get(i).getText().equals("mobile")){

            System.out.println("Trying to select 2: "+textToSelect);

            listItems.get(i).click();
            break;
        }

}

//@AfterTest
//public void tearDown() throws Exception {
//  driver.quit();
//}


}
```

}

[image]

Comment: You want to get an element based on text in it ?

Comment: yes as this code is returning the duplicate data as mentioned by @guy that i am calling the FlipkartSerchfnctn() from test FlipkartSearch() , so what can be the alternate.

Comment: You can use 'contains' function in your XPATH. See my below answer.

Comment: @Hassan: as you can see in the code that the list is picked already, now the job is to get the list element which are in the list, i have added one more attachment where list elements are picked and displayed in the console but am not able to click on the desired element on the basis of name,with this code .  can you update the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling to `FlipkartSerchfnctn()` from test `FlipkartSearch()` and than execute it gain as independent test with the same parameters ("mobile"). That's why you get the results twice.

Either don't call it from test `FlipkartSearch()` or remove the `@Test` annotation from `FlipkartSerchfnctn()`.

Comment: where do i need to call the FlipkartSerchfnctn() , or if there is any other way. i can make a click on the List Element on the basis of the text.

Comment: From where to call it (another test or independent test) is your decision, depends on what you want to check.

Comment: @ Guy : Now : Duplicate Issue is Corrected but what is wrong with this code although it is picking list elements and Displaying them in console but when it comes to click one of them it doesn't works : I have added one more attachment on the top of the code : can you plz check it

Comment: @Milan Where is it stuck? in the `if` condition or in `listItems.get(i).click();`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105588/discussion-between-milan-and-guy).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPATH query for getting an element based on text in it.

```
'//*[contains(text(), "some text present in element")]'
```

OR

```
'//YOUR XPATH TO THAT ELEMENT[contains(text(), "some text present in element")]'
```